# Tangent line on $ e^x $ which is parallel to $y=2x$

Tags: derivatives, solution-verification, exponential-function

At what point on the curve
$$y_1=e^x$$
is the tangent line parallel to
$$y_2=2x$$

---

Below is my solution:

The definition of two lines being **parallel** is that they have the same slope.

For any point on $y_1=e^x$, the slope is $y_1'=e^x$

For any point on $y_2=2x$, the slope is $y_2' = 2$

We want to find the parallel line, so let $y_1'=y_2'$

$\implies e^x=2$

Take the natural log,

$\implies x=ln2$

We want to find the **point** on $y_1$, so we subsitute $x$ in,

$\implies (x,y)=(x,e^x)=(ln2,2)$

Note: If there's anything wrong, please comment below.

Comment: All correct, you did everything right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of two lines being **parallel** is that they have the same slope.

For any point on $y_1=e^x$, the slope is $y_1'=e^x$

For any point on $y_2=2x$, the slope is $y_2' = 2$

We want to find the parallel line, so let $y_1'=y_2'$

$\implies e^x=2$

Take the natural log,

$\implies x=ln2$

We want to find the **point** on $y_1$, so we subsitute $x$ in,

$\implies (x,y)=(x,e^x)=(ln2,2)$

Comment: Looks good.${}{}$